# Merge a dictionary and a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, dictionary

Am trying to combine a dictionary and a list which has dictionaries and an empty dictionary

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
list1 = [{'c': 3}, {'d':4}]
emptydict = {}
emptylist = []
```

Trying to merge and make it a final dictionary which looks like below.

```
final = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd':4}
```

Code:

```
final = {**dict1, **list1[0], **list1[1], **emptydict, **emptylist}
```

Here I dont know the length of list1, can anyone suggest me a better way than this ?

Comment: just loop over the list and use `.update`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using python 3.3+, you can use [ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to merge list of dicts into a single dict. And then use `**` operator to merge `dict1` and `dict(ChainMap(*list1))`.

```
from collections import ChainMap

final = {**dict1, **ChainMap(*list1)}
```

Answer (score 5):

`dict.update` updates an existing dictionary. Unfortunately it’s a mutating method that does not return a value. Therefore adapting it to `functools.reduce` requires a wrapper.

Due to this, I’d be tempted to use a good old loop:

```
final = dict(dict1)
for d in list1:
    final.update(d)
```

But for completeness, here’s a way using `functools.reduce`:

```
import functools

def dict_update(d, v):
    d.update(v)
    return d

final = functools.reduce(dict_update, list1, dict1.copy())
```

Comment: cant we do it without a for loop ?

Comment: using `reduce` for side-effects like this is confusing, better to just do something like `final = reduce(dict_update, list1, dict1.copy())` or whatever

Comment: Note, Python 3.9+ adds the `|` operator to do a non-mutating update, so you could do `reduce(operator.or, list1, dict1)`